# Why I get System.Exception: Correlation failed in ASP.NET and angular OIDC?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have some troubles with correct realization of OpenIdConnect (OIDC) for my angular and asp.net core api application. In my asp.net application I have installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect library. The I have set up the AddOpenIdConnect configuration

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options => {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.ClientId = "<>";
        options.ClientSecret = "<>";
        options.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com/";

        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.UsePkce = true;

        options.CallbackPath = "/Authorization/callback";
    }
);
```

I have added Login function with the Challenge and Callback methods.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthorizationController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("login/")]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return Challenge(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    }

    [HttpGet("callback")]
    public async Task Callback()
    {
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //succeeded
        }
        else
        {
            //failed
        }
    }
}
```

When I make the request from the Angular SPA app to server on button click

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public ssoAuthorize() {
    this.http.get<any>('https://localhost:44351/Authorization/login')
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

I have 2 problems:

1. the server is not redirect me to google auth page[image]
2. When I double click at the red link, I will open in other browser page the auth google form. I login and get other problem[image]

I think it's mean that request should be handled from Angular app not from asp.net. And I don't know how to fix this two problems and is it possble to be fixed?

as othe approach I have tested the logic with angular-auth-oidc-client library for angular but there I have to delegate the Challenge reguest to angular and split the configurations in two applications. What i want to avoid ( if it possilble of course)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AuthModule, LogLevel } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        authority: 'https://accounts.google.com/',
        redirectUrl: 'https://localhost:44351/Authorization/callback',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        clientId: '',
        scope: 'openid email',
        responseType: 'code',
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs';
import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  

  constructor(
    public oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService,
    private http: HttpClient) {
      this.oidcSecurityService
      .checkAuth()
      .subscribe((isAuthenticated) =>
        console.log('app authenticated', isAuthenticated)
      );
  }

  public ssoAuthorize() {
    console.log("userData")
    this.oidcSecurityService.authorize()
  }
```

}